# Spring controller mapping

Tags: spring, controller

Нужна помощь с таким error:

> Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'mainController' method 
>   public java.lang.String com.example.sweater.controller.MainController.greeting(java.util.Map)
>   to {[/],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'greetingController' bean method

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас два контроллера смотрят на один и тот же RequestMapping. Поэтому, происходит отвал башки у спринга. Укажите корректные RequestMapping-и во всех контроллерах и будет Вам счастье.